# Error executing MS Access Delete Query with Left Join

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to run the following delete query to remove parts that are not associated with an order:

```
  DELETE tblParts.ID
  FROM tblParts 
  LEFT JOIN tblOrders ON tblParts.ID = tblOrders.PartID
  WHERE ((tblOrders.OrderID) Is Null);
```

If I use datasheet view or a SELECT query instead of DELETE the query returns the records I would expect to be there.  If I attempt to run the query I get the following error:

> Specify the table containing the records you want to delete.

Doesn't the FROM statement tell Access which table to delete from?  Is my syntax for the delete query incorrect?

Comment: Basic SQL says you delete rows, not columns. Why are you naming a column in your DELETE FROM?

Comment: Other errors I received while troubleshooting ("Query must have at least one destination field") when I did not include anything after the Delete statement and other examples I saw of Delete queries led me to include that.  Removing the `tblParts.ID` from the first line still produced the same "specify the table..." error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE
FROM tblParts 
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT '1'
FROM tblOrders 
WHERE tblOrders.PartID = tblParts.ID
);
```

Comment: Thank you this worked.  Just so I understand for the future, the `SELECT '1'` is doing the same thing as a `NOT IS NULL`?  Would referencing a specific column in the table (OrderID for example) be a more robust solution if there isn't a '1' in the field I want to search?

Comment: SELECT '1' means select anything. It's not related to NOT IS NULL neither do you have to refer to a specific column.